# out of memory error while naming chart

Tags: vba, excel, charts, out-of-memory

I am getting an "out of memory" error while trying to name a chart. I need to be able to reference this chart later in another sub program. Any help appreciated.

```
Sub CreateChart()
' Creates chart for the Quality sheet

Dim sBusiness As String
Dim charttype As String
Dim shChart As Worksheet
Dim num_iss As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim endrng As Integer
Dim currentChart As Chart

Set shChart = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Chart Tool")
sBusiness = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Chart Tool").Range("select_bu").value
charttype = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Chart Tool").Range("select_chart").value
num_iss = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Chart Tool").Range("num_issues").value
endrng = 31 + num_iss


' Chart Placement
   shChart.Shapes.AddChart(xlColumnClustered, _
    Left:=8, Top:=110, _
    Width:=428, Height:=240).Select
    If charttype = "Cost" Then
        ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=shChart.Range(shChart.Cells(2, 32),                 shChart.Cells(3, endrng)) ' souce range
    End If
If charttype = "DPM" Then
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=shChart.Range(shChart.Cells(7, 32), shChart.Cells(8, endrng)) ' souce range
    End If

   ActiveChart.SetElement msoElementCategoryAxisShow
   ActiveChart.SetElement msoElementChartTitleAboveChart ' sets chart title above
   ActiveChart.SetElement msoElementLegendNone ' removes legend
   ActiveChart.SetElement msoElementPrimaryCategoryAxisTitleBelowAxis ' horizontal axis
   ActiveChart.SetElement msoElementPrimaryValueAxisTitleRotated ' Vertical axis
   ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Caption = "Top Issues for " & sBusiness & " by " & charttype ' adds title name
   ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Caption = "Issue" ' adds x-axis title name
   ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Caption = charttype ' adds y-axis title name
   ActiveChart.Name = "ParetoChart"

End Sub
```

Comment: Which line do you get the error on?

Comment: Try `ActiveChart.Parent.Name = "ParetoChart`.

Answer (score 17):

The chart's `.Name` property is Read-Only for embedded chart objects.  You should be able to assign a name to the chart's parent `.ChartObject`.

Since the `ChartObject` is parent of `.Chart`, try:

```
ActiveChart.Parent.Name = "ParetoChart"
```